# How to config a relation in a ComplexType class by EF Core Fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

I have an entity like this:

```
class Book{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   Public Author Author {get;set;}
   Public List<Book> Authors {get;set;}
}

class Author{
   public String Name {get;set;}
   Public Guid BookId {get;set;}
   Public Book Book {get;set;}
}
```

As you see, there is a relation between Book and Book inside Author class.

Table fields should be like this:

```
Book Table:

|  Id  |  Author_Name  |  Author_BookId  |
```

I configure above table with this code:

```
// this line has no problem
builder.OwnsOne(c => c.Author);

// this line cause error
builder.HasOne(x => x.Author.Book)
       .WithMany(x => x.Authors)
       .HasForeignKey(p => p.Author.BookId);
```

**Error:**

> The expression 'x => x.Author.Book' is not a valid property
>   expression. The expression should represent a simple property access:
>   't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'propertyAccessExpression')

Comment: First of all the is the relation many books to one author ?

Comment: Each Book has a relation to Author Book (Recursive). My Problem is `The expression 'x => x.Author.Book' is not a valid property expression.`

Comment: Why `Authors` property is of type `List<Book>`?

Comment: Why "book table" has columns with "author" prefix?

Comment: @GuruStron, This is [ComplexType](https://www.google.com/search?q=complex+type+code+first&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIR883IR883&oq=ComplexType+code&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.5769j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in EF.

Comment: @RAM in EF core this/similar concept is called ["owned types"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

Comment: @GuruStron, Yes

Comment: @RAM have you read the article? It seems there is some misunderstanding based on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GuruStron, I could not find the solution from that article.

Comment: @RAM to have your table looking like the example you need to remove `public List<Book> Authors {get;set;}` and all the set up which is not working for you right now.

Comment: @GuruStron, EF dose not create `Author_BookId`  field.

Comment: @RAM and why should it?

Comment: If you want to implement many-to-many relationship between books and authors there [are](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration) examples how to do it.